# Largest number at singleton

Tags: terminology, order-statistics

I have a funny question - can I call one and only element of singleton the largest number?
For example: I have a singleton : $\{1\}$. Can I call 1 the largest number?

Here is what I think: largest number $n$ from set $L$ is a number for which is true $n - k$ (also from $L$) not equal $0$. And if we have not number to compare = 1 is not a largest number. Also here is we have things like: 1 can be as largest as lowest number, largest = lowest?

So can I call 1 the largest number?
And if I can't - why?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but if your question intends the maximum and minimum of a singleton, then yes: singletons have the equal maximum and minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you define the largest element of a set $A$ with respect to partial ordering relation $\le$ on it?

The usual definition is: $a\in A$ is the largest element if and only if $(\forall x\in A)x\le a$. This *is* satisfied for the only element $a$ in a singleton $A=\{a\}$.

What I am guessing is that you are starting with a different definition, e.g. $(\forall x\in A, x\ne a) x\lt a$. ($p\lt q$ means $p\le q$ and $p\ne q$.) In this case, set of those $x$ is empty and you may be confused whether you can claim something is true *for all* elements of an empty set. Indeed, the very useful convention in math is that you *can*. This is known as "vacuous truth": something is true "in all cases" because there are no examples where it is false - because there are no examples at all! See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth .

Comment: ok i got you. But listen i ask this question because of one situation i have in game. There was 3 players each one had 1 point. And we should do this action: "Find a player with a largest number of points and etc. If we all have same number of points does this action should take place?

Comment: Seems like the makers of the game did not think mathematically when they made up the rules. I am sorry, it looks like you and your friends will need to fill the gaps and decide what to do in that case.

Comment: Can i have your attension for 1 more question? I find the exactly definition for action, maybe it change smth? Here it is: "choose a player with the most souls or tied for the most souls. this player discard soul"

Comment: I am afraid this is not a mathematical question. Possibly the game was manufactured elsewhere and instructions not translated to English very well? I am just as confused with the wording as you are. I am sorry I cannot help much.

Comment: ok anyway thanks a lot!

Comment: @AlexKverr, I disagree with Stinking Bishop. "Find a player with the largest number of souls" is clear and correct English. If multiple people are tied for the most souls, then each one of them is indeed "a player with the largest number of souls" and so any one of them could be chosen to perform the action.

Comment: @MarkS. Let me try to explain why I am unsure.This may be a correct way to say that *one* of those players should be chosen (albeit lacking the instructions *how* to choose that player-throw a die?Oldest player?Explained somewhere else?) or it may be an incorrect way to say that *all* of them should be chosen. (If the instructions say "this player discard [sic] soul"-I can imagine that the writer is just as confused about singular/plural as they are about 3rd person.)But yes,if there is a well-defined procedure in the game that can fairly choose one of many players,then you are probably right.